# Open Webform in a modal, but deny access to the form url

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a Webform being opened in a modal from a menu link. I want to have the modal be the only way to access the form, meaning I don't want someone to type in '/form/(name)' to the URL and access it by page. Is there a way to support opening in a modal but denying page level access in Webform?

Comment: Why would anyone try to access it directly? Is the reasoning purely spam bot related?

Comment: Client does not want them public like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if its the best way but I had something similar to do to allow viewing an entity only on a specified route and if some other conditions were met.
I created an EventSubscriber which basically decides if the user is allowed to access the page or not.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MY_CUSTOM_MODULE\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Custom class RedirectSubscriber.
 */
class RedirectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Custom function to check if we should redirect.
   */
  public function checkForRedirection(GetResponseEvent $event) {

    $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

    // If route is group add form.
    if (isset($route) && $route == "entity.group.add_form") {
      if ("MY CONDITION IS NOT MET") {
        //REDIRECT OR DO SOMETHING ELSE
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('/random-page url'));
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'checkForRedirection',
    ];
  }

}
```

Also, if you decide to do this, don't forget to register your event subscriber in the services.yml file.

```
services:
  MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_redirect_event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\MY_CUSTOM_MODULE\EventSubscriber\RedirectSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

Comment: The thing is, they do have access to view the form, I just want it inaccessible at the page level. Modal only. I don't know if you can see that in the request.

Comment: You could make the event subscriber do something on a certain URL only. In my case I went with current route but I'm sure you could get other services to differentiate different contexts.

Comment: Its just a menu link that points at the same URL. It opens in a modal because the link element has a class.

Comment: You could use the event subscriber to check `$request->query->get('_wrapper_format')`. If not `drupal_modal` throw AccessDeniedHttpException. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21MainContentViewSubscriber.php/constant/MainContentViewSubscriber%3A%3AWRAPPER_FORMAT/9.1.x

Comment: I think Modals are using Ajax, so perhaps you could do something like `\Drupal::request()->isXmlHttpRequest()` and then also throw the `AccessDeniedHttpException` accordingly mentioned by @4k4.